# How does a bytecode interpreter know what line a runtime error occurred on?

Tags: compilation, virtual-machine, programming-languages, bytecode, interpreter

As of now, I am working on a language that compiles to bytecode, and then is ran by a VM.  My question is, when a runtime error occurs, how does the VM know what line of the source code caused the error, as all whitespace is removed during the compilation process.  One thing I would think of is to store a separate array of integers correlating to the bytecode with the line numbers within it, but that sounds extremely memory-inefficient, especially when there are a lot of instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some forms of bytecode contain information about line numbers, method names, etc. which are included to provide better debugging information. In the JVM, for example, method bytecode contains a table that maps ranges of bytecode addresses to source line numbers. That’s a more efficient way of storing it than tagging each bytecode operation with a line number, since there are typically multiple operations per line. It does use extra space, though I wouldn’t classify it as extremely inefficient.

Absent this info, there really isn’t a way for the interpreter to report anything about the original program, since as you’ve noted all that information is otherwise discarded.

This is similar to how compiled executables handle debug info. With debug symbols included, the program has tables mapping code addresses to function names and line numbers. With symbols stripped out, you just have raw instructions and data and there’s no way to reference the original code.